# How to count total number of elements in each column in a tab delimited file

Tags: python

Given a tab delimited file, How to count total number of elements in each column? My file is ~6GB in size.

```
column  count   min max sum mean
80  29573061    2   40  855179253   28.92
81  28861459    2   40  802912711   27.82
82                  40  778234605   27.63
83  27479902    2   40              27.44
84  26800815        40  729443846   27.22
85  26127825    2       701704155   26.86
```

Output:

```
`column` has  6 items in it
`count` has 5 items in it
 and so on
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you mean by "elements" in this case?

Comment: pl see the post. I edited it lil bit

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
with open("count.tsv", "rb") as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        counts += Counter(k for k,v in row.items() if v.strip())
```

which gives

```
>>> counts
Counter({'column': 6, 'mean': 6, 'count': 5, 'max': 5, 'sum': 5, 'min': 4})
```

Although, as noted by @Cartroo, you might have to change the emptiness criterion depending on exactly what values you want to consider empty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean count the occurrences of non-whitespace text, something like this:

```
import collections

titles = None
counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
with open("file.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        items = line.split("\t")
        if titles is None:
            if items:
                titles = [i.strip() for i in items]
            continue
        for i in xrange(min(len(titles), len(items))):
            if items[i].strip():
                counts[titles[i]] += 1

for column, count in counts.iteritems():
    print "Column %s has %d items" % (column, count)
```

Note that this code relies on no row having more elements than the title row, although it does handle shorter rows. I'm sure there are more concise ways using list comprehensions and the like, but I thought that a more verbose style might be clearer.

If you meant summing the values themselves or similar, you'll need to do something a little more clever with the `items` list. Purely by way of example, to find the total sum of the "count" column:

```
total_count = 0
with open("file.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd
        items = line.split("\t")
        try:
            total_count += int(items[1])
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but hopefully this examples give you an idea of how to go about this sort of processing in a simple way.

Comment: Instead of doing `for line in fd: line.split('\t')` consider using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Agreed the `csv` module is useful, although it does depend on how the OP wants to handle quotes. For example, does an empty-quoted element count as a proper element or not? Depending on exactly what's required, the `csv` module might actually do too much. Plus, using `split()` is so simple it's hard to beat, if it meets the requirements.

Comment: It looks like the OP's input file only has numeric data in it so your concern about quote handling doesn't seem justified.

Comment: Sure, if these examples are truly representative of the full scope of the data expected - I don't like to make too many assumptions, though. (^_^)  The important thing is that the OP is aware of the consequences of different approaches, so they can pick one as appropriate. There's certainly a good likelihood that the `csv` module will just do the right thing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

1. Read the file line by line
2. [Split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) each line by a tab delimiter ('\t')

   - For each split, iterate through each element of the list

     - Check for an empty string value

       - If there is an empty string, don't do anything
       - If there is not an empty string, increment that column's count

For the column counts, you could just use another list. For example counts is our list, counts[0] will be the number of elements of the column "column", counts[1] will be the number of elements of the column "count", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Map reduce library is made for such big data processing. This is a good idea to use it. 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview#Downloading_the_Mapreduce_Library